# Formula for Solution to Linear system Ax=b.

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't own a linear algebra textbook. What is the formula for the solution to the linear system Ax=b?

The Fredholm alternative states Ax=b has a solution if and only if $$b \perp ker A^\ast$$ So, let this be true. Then, what is the solution?

I anticipate the formula is something like $$x=(A+P)^{-1}b + ker A$$ for some operator P. Maybe I need to invert an operator on a coset space. I forgot. Please don't give an algorithm, google gives me this but that's not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any solution exists, one is $A^+ b$ where $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$.  And then the general solution is $A^+ b + \text{Ker}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you. That article should be enough, but out of curiosity, do you know a book that has this? I would like to obtain a "serious" linear algebra book for myself.

Comment: You might try Strang, "[Linear Algebra and its Applications](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9A7jBQAAQBAJ)"